# Getting the last timestamp from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to get the last (ie. greatest) timestamp value provided to Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not sensible (!), to do this by retrieving all columns in the system and keeping track of the latest timestamp.

Why do you want to do this? You could perhaps write a special column containing the latest timestamp, and update it every time you insert/update/delete anything else...

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, and is exposed through the Thrift interface.  This was provided by thobbs in [phpcassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa) through the following patch:

https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/commit/05830b0c275905e30b504813a838370cad40c2a1

```
public $include_timestamp = false;
```